# Georeferencing using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, georeferencing

I have a .tiff image that I am trying to overlay in google earth. For that I require to georeference it first.
The image projection is UTM with NAD83 as datum. I know the lat/long of the four corners of the image.

I am doing the following way:

1. gdalinfo to get the four coordinates.
2. gdal_translate to specify lat/long info
3. gdal2tiles.py to tile the image.

The only thing is bugging me is that I never specified UTM and NAD83, then how come it can overlay my image?
Does anybody know how to specify this projection information?

Answer (score 26):

follow this way:

1. Find your spatial reference code from [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4269/)
2. Learn your tif file upper left coordinate and lower right coordinate.
3. use this command for making it coordinated:

   - `gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_ullr ullon ullat lrlon lrlat -a_srs EPSG:4269 input.tif output.tif`
4. use this command for mercator:(epsg:3857)

   - `gdalwarp -of GTiff  -t_srs EPSG:3857 input.tif output.tif`
5. then use gdal2tiles.py to tile.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I need to overlay my UTM Projection onto google earth which uses WGS84 as datum. So shouldn't I set the target reference system to ESPG:4326 ?

Comment: @Akd Aragon's gdalwarp to EPSG:3857 is good for Google. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857 for more.

Comment: According [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) and test: `-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry` or with lat/lon terms `-a_ullr ullon ullat lrlon lrlat` is the correct way to use the command.

Comment: I have edited the post for the correct order of x and y in `-a_ullr`.

Comment: I try to georeferencing a tiff also, but I wonder how can we know the upper left coordinate and lower right coordinate ? Could you help me @Aragon ?