# Tiling high resolution image using GDAL tools

Tags: gdal

I have a .tif image that I georeferenced using QGIS utility. It was originally in UTM with NAD83 as datum.
I need to make tiles out of it and get a kml file to overlay onto google earth.
Here's how I am doing it:

gdal2tiles.py -p geodetic -k filename

My image is slightly off where it should have been on google earth.What is going wrong here? Also do we need to warp the image using gdalwarp as my image though georeferenced is still a projection, it's not for a round globe. If yes, what command/parameters I need?

Comment: Akd; Is your image properly georeferenced before you attempt to tile? It would help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Yes I georeferenced it using QGIS. I supplied coordinates for 10 points on the image whose coordinates were known to me. I used "nearest neighbour" resamling method with "thin plate spline" transformation type in QGIS utility.

Comment: try removing "-p geodetic"

Comment: What is the reported error when georeferencing?  How 'off' are you?

Answer (score 1):

Try gdalwarp-ing the image to Lat/Lon WGS84 (EPSG:4326) before running gdal2tiles:
    gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 srcfile dstfile

Comment: I agree with @DanDye, for the sake of troubleshooting, it's probably best to go to either WGS84 (epsg:4326), or maybe even Web Mercator (epsg:3857) first. Then run gdal2tiles. The gdal utilities have my greatest respect, but any time I run into a "gotcha" on a compound task that includes a reprojection, my first move is always to put the reprojection in a stand alone task, then pick up from there.

Answer (score 0):

@Akd, check out my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27301/3071). if my answer dont meet the needs of you, take a look at [here](http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/12180/9492/).

i hope it helps you...