# Technique using GDAL to overlay / fit one PNG map to directly overlay on another?

Tags: gdal, overlay, gdalwarp

I have one .PNG basemap with known North edge of Latitude = 52.48, a South edge of Latitude =  21.94, an east edge of Longitude = -61.87 and a west edge of Longitude = -129.37.

And I have another PNG image overlay with a known North edge of Latitude = 50.03, a South edge of Latitude =  22.02, an east edge of Longitude = -67.24 and a west edge of Longitude = -124.99.

Is there a way using GDAL or other simple scripting tools to process the second PNG image to be in an output that directly overlays (same x/y dimensions) the basemap?

I have no trouble generating map tiles that overlay each other beautifully - but I seem to be having no luck figuring out the syntax of the seemingly simpler case.

Help in the form of a simple example is much appreciated!

To be clear: the goal is an output .png file that has the exact same x/y dimensions as the basemap, and which can directly overlay on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED after feedback from question poster.

Step 1: if files are not georeferenced, try the methods described here, 
 [Georeferencing using GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27297/georeferencing-using-gdal-tools).
Also world files could work for weither png or tif (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file; http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html).

Step 2: two methods could work for the clipping. Trying gdaltranslate with the following option  `-projwin ulx uly lrx lry:`  would work if you have the coordinates as the question seems to imply.

OR, you have the option of using  `gdaltindex newclip.shp basemap.png` to create a clip shapefile. The shapefile can be used in the following way

`gdalwarp -cutline /path/to/newclip.shp -crop-to-cutline oldimage.tif newimage.tif`

remember that the path I show is for linux. Windows would be C:\something\clip.shp. Also, the example does not account for CRS. There is the option of replacing the cutline with `-te xmin ymin xmax ymax`

helpful link: http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html

hope this helps :)

Comment: Perhaps the part I am missing is that all I have is a plain .png file and the edge coordinates - the file is not a TIF with this information embedded, and gdalwarp doesn't know where to begin.

Comment: So you need to georeference the file as well? hmmm I'll get back to you.

Comment: I think I am georeferencing the maps fine now, and turning them into GTiff's.  But...  I am not sure I am any closer to the goal of getting an output .png that has the same x/y dimensions as the basemap, and can directly overlay.

Comment: I was using the -te option, but now that I have converted the basemap into a GTiff (and confirmed the details via gdalinfo) I have tried the -crop_to_cutline option you described, and it fails without output or error: gdalwarp -cutline ./output43264.tif -crop_to_cutline output4.tif outputN.tif

Comment: Hi radven, I hope my newest edits are helpful. GOod luck. any questions? just ask :)

Comment: Your guidance got me on the right track, and everything is working now.  Thanks!!!

Comment: I didn't realize I was going to learn something when I first tried to answer your question :)  Thanks, and I am glad it works now.